# SQL server concat SP output with multiple columns into one string in select query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a legacy SP that always returns one row (I cannot change that SP) and I need to use it somehow in a select statement for multiple rows (for each row I need to call that SP). What would be the best approach to that? Somehow wrap it into TVF and call that function?

And the second question is what would be the best approach to concat all fields returned by that SP to single string. lets say SP returns
ID, Key, Value I would need to concat it to a string like "ID: 1, Key: NSR, Value: 154.4"

Comment: Which is the SQL Server version?

Comment: SQL Serv 2014 SP2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call a stored procedure for each row, you will need to loop either with a WHILE loop or a CURSOR.   Whether you wrap this in a TVF or not is up to you.

To concatenate the fields returned by the SP, you should use variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WHILE` loop to call the stored procedure multiple times. You can use `CONCAT` for making all column values in one string. It's nice because it is handling the `NULL` values.

```
SELECT CONCAT('ID:', [ID], ', Key:', [Key], ', Value:', [Value]);
```

Anyone, if I were you, and performance do matters, I would rewrite the SP to support handling multiple rows. If you are not allowed to change the SP, create new one - use it new development, while the old one is used in the old code.

Comment: Ok maybe I should specify that this SP has like 60output fields and I am not really found of listing it all if possible. I tried to do that with FOR XML statement but it worked fine for regular table but not really for SP